# How to extract .emz files from word in c#

Tags: c#

I have Ms-word file which is having embedded images in .emz format and want to extract those .emz images and want to store in particular folder.
I am trying this but did not get any useful solution

```
var package = Package.Open(this.FilePath);
// Get the embedded files names.
foreach (var packagePart in package.GetParts())
        {
          using (var packagePartStream = packagePart.GetStream())
                using (var packagePartMemoryStream = new sys.MemoryStream())
                {
                    packagePartStream.CopyTo(packagePartMemoryStream);
                    string fileName1 = packagePart.Uri.ToString().Remove(0, embeddingPartString.Length);                     
                    File.WriteAllBytes(fileName1,packagePartMemoryStream.ToArray());
             }
       }
```

Comment: is word or path ?

Comment: Ms-Word........

Comment: so you are reading msword file and try to extract path .emz ...?

Comment: I want those .emz files to store in particular folder